# Spring.addDecoration using dojo and HTML clash on event fire

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dojo

I am using a dojo widget that in `roo` generated `.jspx` files. Where following is my code parts

```
<form:select name="halfOrFulDay" id="_monitoringType_id${rowCounter.count}" Style="width:120px" onchange="someProcess()">
   <form:option value="--Select--" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
   <form:option value="Half Day" >Half Day</option>
   <form:option value="Full Day" >Full Day</option>
   <form:option value="None" >None</option>
</form:select>
<script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : '_monitoringType_id${rowCounter.count}', widgetType: 'dijit.form.FilteringSelect', widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: 'In Complete Data',hasDownArrow : true}})); </script>
```

My problem is, I am not able to fire **onchange** event as soon as I applied Spring.addDecoration(). Is there any attribute that i can set within **widgetAttrs** ? Something like:

widgetAttrs : {**onchange : someProcess** ,promptMessage: 'In Complete Data',hasDownArrow : true}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dijit.form.FilteringSelect is not a regular dom node. It's a dijit widget... 
Its onchange event is attached to a particular dom node of the widget template, and it's attached to the widget's extension point called "onChange" (mind the capital C).

Your example should be :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
        elementId : '_monitoringType_id${rowCounter.count}', 
        widgetType: 'dijit.form.FilteringSelect', 
        widgetAttrs : {
            promptMessage: 'In Complete Data',
            hasDownArrow : true,
            onChange : function(evt) {
               // Your event code here
            }
        }
    })); 
</script>
```

You should read about this here : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#creating-extension-points

For any widgets you use through spring, you will find the corresponding documentation here : http://dojotoolkit.org/api/

Just expand the "dijit" tree node, then select your widget, then have a look at the list of custom events it supports in the "Event summary" section.

Comment: Thanks Philippe :-) . It worked for me. And thanks again for suggesting appropriate documentation.
Cheers